# Solve a linear sytem of differential equations (Cauchy problem)

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I'm trying to solve a linear Cauchy problem (which should have a unique solution) as:

$\dot{X}=Q^{11}X+Q^{12}Y,X(0)=I$

$\dot{Y}=Q^{21}X+Q^{22}Y,Y(0)=0$

The matrices $Q^{11}, Q^{12}, Q^{21}, Q^{22}$ are two by two matrices with constants coefficients.

I don't know if I have a syntax error but it comes unevaluated every time I try. here is my code:

```
sol = DSolve[{X'[t] == Q11[1/(1 - α)].X[t] + Q12[1/(1 - α)].Y[t], 
   Y'[t] == Q21[1/(1 - α)].X[t] + Q22[1/(1 - α)].Y[t], 
   X[0] == IdentityMatrix[2], Y[0] ==  ConstantArray[0., {2, 2}]}, {X, Y}, t]
```

It returns:

```
DSolve[{Derivative[1][X][
    t] == {{1/5 + 2/3 (-(1/5) + Sqrt[47/65]/4), 
       1/3 (-(1/5) + Sqrt[47/65]/4)}, {1/3 (1/5 - Sqrt[394]/65), 
       1/5 + 4/3 (-(1/5) + Sqrt[394]/65)}}.X[
      t] + {{-2 (6849/4000000 + (169 (-(1/5) + Sqrt[47/65]/4)^2)/
          10000), -2 (9/10000 + (
          169 (-(1/5) + Sqrt[47/65]/4) (-(1/5) + Sqrt[394]/65))/
          10000)}, {-2 (9/10000 + (
          169 (-(1/5) + Sqrt[47/65]/4) (-(1/5) + Sqrt[394]/65))/
          10000), -2 (9/10000 + (169 (-(1/5) + Sqrt[394]/65)^2)/
          10000)}}.Y[t], 
  Derivative[1][Y][
    t] == {{-(10000/1521), -(5000/1521)}, {-(5000/1521), 20000/
       1521}}.X[
      t] + {{-(1/5) - 2/3 (-(1/5) + Sqrt[47/65]/4), 
       1/3 (-(1/5) + Sqrt[394]/65)}, {1/
        3 (1/5 - Sqrt[47/65]/4), -(1/5) - 
        4/3 (-(1/5) + Sqrt[394]/65)}}.Y[t], X[0] == {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, 
  Y[0] == {{0., 0.}, {0., 0.}}}, {X, Y}, t]
```

Does anybody know what I may be doing wrong or why it is not solving them?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! I changed it but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the initial conditions for `Y`, it is a scalar and that does not play well with `Dot` (as in `{{ ... }}.Y[t]`). So you probably want `Y[0] == ConstantArray[0., {2, 2}]` as initial condition. Then at least `NDSolve` is able to produce a solution. `DSolve` seems to dislike matrix-valued ODEs and stays unevaluated. (`DSolve` *should* be able to solve this because it is just a linear ODE system with constant coeffients.)

```
Q11 = {{1/5 + 2/3 (-(1/5) + Sqrt[47/65]/4), 1/3 (-(1/5) + Sqrt[47/65]/4)}, {1/3 (1/5 - Sqrt[394]/65), 1/5 + 4/3 (-(1/5) + Sqrt[394]/65)}};
Q12 = {{-2 (6849/4000000 + (169 (-(1/5) + Sqrt[47/65]/4)^2)/10000), -2 (9/10000 + (169 (-(1/5) + Sqrt[47/65]/4) (-(1/5) + Sqrt[394]/65))/10000)}, {-2 (9/10000 + (169 (-(1/5) + Sqrt[47/65]/4) (-(1/5) + Sqrt[394]/65))/10000), -2 (9/ 10000 + (169 (-(1/5) + Sqrt[394]/65)^2)/10000)}};
Q21 = {{-(10000/1521), -(5000/1521)}, {-(5000/1521), 20000/1521}};
Q22 = {{-(1/5) - 2/3 (-(1/5) + Sqrt[47/65]/4), 1/3 (-(1/5) + Sqrt[394]/65)}, {1/3 (1/5 - Sqrt[47/65]/4), -(1/5) - 4/3 (-(1/5) + Sqrt[394]/65)}};
NDSolve[{
  X'[t] == Q11.X[t] + Q12.Y[t], 
  Y'[t] == Q21.X[t] + Q22.Y[t],
  X[0] == {{1, 0}, {0, 1}},
  Y[0] == ConstantArray[0., {2, 2}]
  },
 {X, Y},
 {t, 0, 1}
 ]
```

However, rephasing the system in a vectorial one does also not help with `DSolve`. But the symbolic solution should be obtain by the matrix exponential function as follows:

```
L = Simplify[ArrayFlatten[{{Q11, Q12}, {Q21, Q22}}]];
newL = D[Flatten[L.Array[x, {4, 2}]], {Flatten[Array[x, {4, 2}]], 1}];
sol = t \[Function]  Evaluate[MatrixExp[t newL].Flatten[{{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, ConstantArray[0., {2, 2}]}]];
```

Here `sol[t]` corresponds to `Flatten[{X[t],Y[t]}]`.

What am I doing there? Well, basically, I am fusing `X` and `Y` together to a $4 \times 2$-matrix `Array[x, {4, 2}]` and all the `Qij` to a $4 \times 4$-matrix `L` that acts on $4 \times 2$-matrices via multiplication from the left. Then `Flatten[L.Array[x, {4, 2}]]` is the flattened out right hand side of the new system. In order to get the new $8 \times 8$ system matrix `newL`, I simply differentiate with respect to the $8$-vector `Flatten[Array[x, {4, 2}]]`. So the new system looks basically like `x'[t] == newL.x[t]` and since `newL` is independent of `x[t]`, we can use the matrix exponential to solve the system.

One can also solve this with `DSolve` if one "unrolls" the system by hand:

```
DSolve[Simplify@Join[
   Thread[
    Flatten[Table[x[i, j]'[t], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]] == 
     Flatten[Q11.Table[x[i, j][t], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}] + 
       Q12.Table[y[i, j][t], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]]
    ],
   Thread[
    Flatten[Table[y[i, j]'[t], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]] == 
     Flatten[Q21.Table[x[i, j][t], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}] + 
       Q22.Table[y[i, j][t], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]]
    ],
   Thread[
    Flatten[Table[x[i, j][0], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]] == 
     Flatten[IdentityMatrix[2]]
    ],
   Thread[
    Flatten[Table[y[i, j][0], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]] == 
     Flatten[ConstantArray[0, {2, 2}]]
    ]
   ],
 Join[Flatten[Table[x[i, j], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]], 
  Flatten[Table[y[i, j], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]]],
 t
 ]
```

Comment: I agree that DSolve should be able to solve this... Do you know why it doesn't?

Comment: Nah, dunno, sorry. But the system is easy enough to solve with `MatrixExp`.